# Where can I get a Lyx Layout for Bioinformatics by Oxford University Press?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Oxford University Press provides a LaTeX class for their Bioinformatics journal.  Does anyone know if a Lyx .layout has been created for it?

I've been trying my hand at creating the layout myself, but the learning curve is pretty dang steep.

Comment: YoU can download this layout: https://github.com/telegraphic/Oxford-LyX-Thesis-Template

Comment: That is a thesis layout, not a layout for Bioinformatics article.